# Something wrong with my segmented bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stat

I want to plot a segmented bar plot in ggplot2. Here is part of my [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwEbV.png), I want to plot the proportion of output(0 and 1) for each x1(0 and 1). But when I use the following code, what I plot is just black bars without any segmentation. What's the problem in here?

```
  fig = ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=x1, fill=output)) + geom_bar(stat="count", width=0.5, position='fill')
```

The output plot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbG5j.png)

Comment: Try `position = "stack"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need factor variables for your task:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x1=sample(0:1,100,replace = T),output=sample(0:1,100,replace = T))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(x1), fill = as.factor(output))) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count")+
  labs(x="x11")
```

which give me:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works. Now maybe I need to learn about as.factor here. I'm pretty new to R and ggplot. Thanks again!